# Calculating chromosome number in meiosis: Why is the crossbreed between a fox and a dog (dox) sterile?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics

Given the following example/question (originally found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDRDy.jpg)):

[image]

I worked out the haploid number of the dox to be 29 and the diploid number of the dox to be 58. 58 is an even number, so surely 29 homologous pairs of chromosomes can form for the dox to be fertile. Why is it sterile?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the original question as a **text** and not as an **image**. Moreover, the image is also not posted in SE and any user has to go to an external site.

Comment: I would rework the the title of your question as in its current form it doesn't properly reflect the content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not simply a question of math, just determining if the diploid number is even or odd. If it was that easy, all hybrids with an even diploid number would be fertile, and that doesn't happen. The problem is way more complex, and it has to do with chromosome pairing.

In the question described, we have the following numbers:

- *Canis lupus* (dog): 2N = 78, therefore N = 39;
- *Vulpes vulpes* (fox): 2N = 38, therefore N = 19;

Now, let's suppose, in an exaggerated simplification, that **all** 19 chromosomes in the fox's gamete find an *exact* homologous in the dog's gamete (again, this is very unlikely). So, in this oversimplified scenario, we would have 19 pairs of homologous chromosomes in the hybrid's cells.

However, even if that's the case, we still have 20 chromosomes in the dog's gamete that didn't find any homologue in the fox's gamete.

That mismatch, alone, is enough to block meiosis, particularly at the [pachitene checkpoint](http://www.nature.com/hdy/journal/v102/n1/full/hdy200884a.html).